# Calculate Dq(x)

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

Let A be a symmetric $m \times m$ matrix, and $q(x)=x\cdot Ax$ a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Question:
Calculate $Dq(x)$; write your answer in vector notation.

Does anyone knows the answer on this question? I don't know what they mean with a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^m$. I know that if $A$ is the unit matrix, $q(x)$ would look like $x_{1}^{2}+\dots +x_{m}^{2}$ but i don't know if $A$ is an unit matrix.

Answer (score 0):

ok let us take example

take for example
$x=[x_1 ,x_2]$

```
A =

     1     2
     2     3
```

now clearly  you can calculate $X*A*X'$ which  in this case would be quadratic  polynomial,can you differentiate second order polynomial?you  do it with high,for example

http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf

Comment: Yes thanks, i can write $q(x)$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_{i}^2\cdot a_{ii} + 2\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_i\cdot x_j\cdot a_{ij}$.  I think that $Dq(x)$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{m}2x_{i}\cdot a_{ii}+2\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_i\cdot a_{ij}+2\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_j\cdot a_{ij}$. Could you confirm this?

Comment: yes of course,you should use product rule

Comment: start to confirm this using simple examples and lower order